# Removing double quotes and delimiter from a string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have String "abc", "def". How can I remove the double quotes and comma from a single regular expression.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Sorry, please rephrase.

Comment: You should really mention what you have tried so far, this looks like a homework question

Comment: Sorry about that. I have a code something like this:
for (String country: countrLable){
         String [] info = country.split(",");
           for(i = counter; i<info.length; i++){
I am not sure how to split comma and delimited quotes at the same time

Comment: @user2810293 To add more informations about your problem simply [edit] your question. Don't post important informations in comments (not everyone reads them, and they don't support proper code formatting).

Answer (score 0):

tokenize the string with `,` as delimiter with

```
String yourString = "\"abc\",\"def\"";
String[] data = yourString.split(",");
```

and then remove the quotes with `substring`

```
for(String s: data){
    String someString = s.substring(1, s.length()-1);
}
```

Comment: It would be more sensible to first scrub the string and then split it. No need for a loop here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] a)
{
  String str="\"abc\",\"def\"";
   String temp=str.replaceAll("\"","").replaceAll(",", "");
  System.out.println(temp);
  }
```

using replaceAll it is working...... hope it will help....

Answer (score -3):

Use `string.replace("\"","")`?

Replaces quotation mark with a string of zero length.

Comment: Thanks, how can I remove the delimiter as well?